# Connect to soap service via proxy on different ports

Tags: networking, iptables, centos6, tunnel, soap

I need to connect from a server to a web-service server to consume a `SOAP` service but due to restrictions in place I cannot connect directly.

They did however give me a proxy server that can, but it runs on the service on a different port:

`[webserver]` ----- `[proxy:48650]` ----- `[webservice:8601]`

Note (if it wasn't clear yet): I've simplified the hostnames as their very long corporate things and would needlessly complicate the question.

The big problem is that the `WSDL` of webservice contains a lot of referrals with the absolute URL (so `webservice:8601`). The includes go more than 1 level deep (so downloading the WSDL and doing a search/replace will not get me much further).

I've added a rule to `/etc/hosts` on webserver:

`127.0.0.1 webservice`

The underlying idea is to somehow proxy the 8601 port on localhost and make the soap-client think it is actually connecting to the webservice (via the proxy).

An `SSH tunnel` is unfortunately not an option to the proxy, same security reasons. I cannot make an SSH connection to the proxy.

`iptables` is a possibility but I can find a set of rules that takes a port on localhost (8601) and redirects it to an external host/different port (proxy:48650). Most of them are for incoming traffic.

I've been wasting a lot of time on this and am getting desperate. Is there anyone here who can provide me with some hints/solutions?

Pretty please?

Comment: Exactly what sort of proxy is that supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry I had to inquire for that here. It's an iptables forward.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the entry from your hosts file and use iptables to DNAT the traffic.

On your local machine:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d webservice -p tcp --dport 8601 -j DNAT --to proxy:48650
```

OR, on an intermediate router you'll need to use the `PREROUTING` chain instead of the `OUTPUT` chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d webservice -p tcp --dport 8601 -j DNAT --to proxy:48650
```

**NOTE:** You must use the IP Address of the proxy in the `--to` argument; iptables won't do name resolution there. You can use the hosting of the `webservice` as the argument to `-d` though.